# Room make WHERE IN for two columns

Tags: android, sqlite, android-room

if I have list of some id's I can simply create query which will contain items matching specified id's:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE owner IN (:owners)")
fun getData(owners: List<String>): List<Data>
```

But how to do same with complex primary key consisting of two columns? E.g. entity looks like:

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["owner", "uuid"])
Data (
    val owner: String,
    val uuid: String,
    val data: String
)
```

How can I query Data knowing owner/uuid pairs?

Comment: So the question is how you can get a SELECT to find all of the owner and uuid given from a List<String>?

Comment: I not even know which list I need to provide to the DAO. Currently it is List<Pair<String, String>>.

Comment: Can't you do ```SELECT * FROM data WHERE owner IN :owners AND uuid IN :uuids``` and pass in both lists as params to the DAO method?

Comment: It will be different condition (... || ... || ...) && (... || ... || ...). But I need (owner && uuid) || (owner && uuid) ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest next workaround:

1. In your query you can use one "virtual" search field made of two your fields ("owner" and "uuid"). You can for example concat them with some placeholder (underscore, for example).
2. Prepare list of these "virtual" search fields' values beforehand (using the same algorithm) and put it to your `getData` function in your Dao.

Something like that:

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM data WHERE owner||'_'||uuid IN : ownersWithUuids")
fun getData(ownersWithUuids: List<String>): List<Data>
```

For example if you want to search values:

- owner = "123", uuid = "222"
- owner = "444", uuid = "111"

you should put into your method list:

```
listOf("123_222", "444_111")
```